# What is the equivalent of the SQL Server CHAR function?

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, encoding, utf-8

SQL Server has [`CHAR ( integer_expression )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql), so I can do

```
SELECT CHAR(65)
```

What is the equivalent on Postgresql? I have tried `SELECT E'\0x65';` but I get

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Comment: I think there are two problems, here 0x92 is 146. That's >128 which means it's not ASCII and is instead encoding-dependent. That doesn't seem to be what you want. Perhaps you just mean `92` (which is different from 0x92). Or, perhaps you do mean 0x92 which is valid in Win1252 but would require [reencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Because that's a fundamentally different problem I'm going to alter your question to use 65 which is ASCII for `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the docs on [*PostgreSQL String Functions and Operators*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER),

> **`chr(int)`** Character with the given code. For `UTF8` the argument is treated as a Unicode code point. For other multibyte encodings the argument must designate an `ASCII` character. The `NULL` `(0)` character is not allowed because text data types cannot store such bytes.

Demonstrating `chr()`, its inverse, and both.,

```
# SELECT chr(65), ascii('A'), chr(ascii('A'));
 chr | ascii | chr 
-----+-------+-----
 A   |    65 | A
(1 row)
```

In your question you use [`E''` (the *"bytea Hex Format"*)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.9) which is totally possible too, though I wouldn't suggest it for simple problems like this. You can do that like this,

```
SELECT E'\x41'; -- 41 is hex for 65 (in base 10)
SELECT E'\101'; -- 101 is octal for 65 (in base 10)
 ?column? 
----------
 A
(1 row)
```